¿Unit test con java 6?
Pasa y resulta que este proyecto tiene como finalidad funcionar en versiones de java 1.6, 1.8 y 11, pero al construirlo sobre 1.6 me arroja el siguiente error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project erp-project-catalog-client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] ProjectTest.java:[9,35] cannot access org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
[ERROR] bad class file: org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.class(org/junit/jupiter/api:Assertions.class)
[ERROR] class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
[ERROR] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
Existe alguna versión (de casualidad) que lo sea o alguna configuración para evitar ese error al construir el proyecto sobre 1.6?
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
   <version>5.10.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <type>jar</type>
</dependency>


Como puedes ver en la documentación oficial de Junit, Junit 5, o Júpiter como se le llama a esta versión necesita que tengas mínimo java 8.
Así que te tocará usar en su lugar JUnit 4
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


Excelente,  con la versión 2.19.1 de maven-surefire-plugin quedó perfectamente funcional para 1.6, gracias
